# How i calculate loading time of a application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a loading bar at the initial of the game which is customized loading bar.
for that i need to calculate the loading percentage to show loading progress. Is there any way to calculate the loading time of the application? please help me.

If i add Default.png in my resources folder, it will seen at the time of application loading. How it works? I want to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Default.png to your liking and even exchange it between application starts, but it's still a static image that cannot be animated. It's displayed while the iPhone OS is bootstrapping your application. Once the application enters your own main function, you can display whatever you want - from this point on, what's loaded and what's displayed is under your control.

Regarding progress display, I can only speak from a game developers point of view. Normally, you know how many resources you're loading (textures, sound files,...) so you can load e.g. one resource per main-loop pass and display the progress accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure about being able to change the Default.png.  It's part of your application bundle, which should be read-only.  Even if you could change it, it seems like it would alter the cryptographic signature of your application.

Comment: When I tinkered with iPhone development end of last year, there was a flaw in the codesign tool which doesn't follow symlinks. That way, you can point a symlink to an arbitrary file and replace it's contents on the fly without making the sealed app invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your progress bar needs to be based on *progress* and not time. Remember that some hardware is faster than others. The 2G iPod touch is the fastest with (I think) the original iPhone the slowest.

Your `Default.png` image is entirely static. Sounds like you'd take a screenshot of your loading screen when it has zero progress and use that.